# How do I kill/abort/terminate/exit a running query when specific if condition is fullfilled?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a script in Msn SQL Server Management Studio 17 (I belive running a Msn SQL Server 14) that are supposed to create tables in a specific database. There are posibilities that some of the tables is not created. If that happens I have a if statement that checks for that. When the tables are created the script are supposed to do a print, go forward and keep running. This works fine. But, when the table is not created. I want the script to do a print, saying the tables is not created and then stop.

I've set it upp with an if statement like below. @sid is declared as int and given the value from @@spid. Since I can't copy my code from the environment due to security, I've rewritten it. So if there are some misspellings in code I say works above, it's because I've misspelled it in my rewriting because everything works exept for the query termination part. :)

```
if object_id(@database + '.dbo.' + @table, 'U') is not null
begin
/* print and some actions, this works absolutely correct. */
end
else
begin
print 'Saying the table don't exists in the database.' --This works fine.
kill spid @sid --This doesn't work. I've also tried kill spid = @sid, kill @@spid, kill @sid, kill spid spid @@spid
end
```

How should I put this to get the print out and then exit the query?

Comment: What's wrong with `return;`

Comment: Or `raiseerror()`?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. There is no wrong with "return", more than that it was so long ago I solved this kind of problem that I forgot about it. It did the trick absolutely nicely and was the command I was looking for. I'm unfamiliar wit raiseerror(), but even that did the trick and I think that command provided some functionality that might be useful in a later stage for this roll out. :)